# Hide specific item in lookup column

Tags: sharepoint-2010

My form has lookup column which gets data from another list but I want to remove/hide particular item in the lookup column.

For example; My look up columns gets A;B;C;D;E entries from another list now I don't want to show E in my lookup column .

I can accomplish this if I customize the form in InfoPath but my list(which has lookp column) must be used as "Data sheet view" and InfoPath customization don't work on data sheet view.

Tried using JQuery but didn't work.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you should never be using jQuery for security related practices.  What if a user has javascript turned off?

This question seems to cry out of item level permissions.  That said, item level permissions is generally considered a last resort at best type of practice, so I would suggest you first consider whether or not item E could be moved into a different list entirely, which is only viewable by certain parties.

Comment: Thanks Robert, However Item E is in configuration list which is used throughout app programmatically.If I put item level permission on  "E" then it may not be accessible in program as well. Right?

Comment: Well, you could always replace E with "Surpervisor's Choice", then place E in a "Supervisor's Configuration List", which is looked up in a separate column.  Or whatever list this lookup column is on could be for employees, and supervisors have a seperate list with better options, etc.

I don't know your environment, so I don't know what is preferred or more complex.  But yes, you would have to be careful with item level permissions and would have to test thoroughly to check who and what does and does not have access.